# Problemas com helpers no laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5

Criei uma pagina PHP e fiz algumas funções nela para auxiliar no meu projeto.

Eu adicionei no *composer* essa página através dessa linha:

```
"files": ["App/FunAuxiliar.php"]
```

Porém quando subi o sistema para produção, não consegui chamar as funções que criei para essa página.

Alguém tem uma solução?

Comment: Qual é o sistema operacional do seu servidor em Produção?

Comment: O server é linux? Vale lembrar que ele é case sensitive e se voce estiver buscando com minuscula não vai encontrar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente, o problema está em você estar usando `App\FunAuxiliar.php`, ao invés de `app\FunAuxiliar.php`.

Que eu saiba, no Laravel, a pasta padrão da aplicação é `app` e não `App`.

Em sistema operacionais como Windows, não faz diferença. Mas em Linux faz, já que Linux é case-sensitive (diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas).

É comum acontecer esse problema quando você programa sua aplicação em Windows e sobe ela para um servidor Linux.

Por isso, a recomendação sempre é referenciar as pastas de fato como o valor dela é, e não mudando um caso (maísculo ou minúsculo) de uma letra do nome do diretório, como vcê fez.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas o meu problema é que eu alterei esse arquivo no composer.json, e não existe esse arquivo no meu servidor, não sei se devo passar ele para o servidor e se sim, se devo só copiar ele.

Comment: @AndréTripodeColognesi como assim? Se você precisa das funções, você precisa do arquivo.

Comment: @AndréTripodeColognesi copia o arquivo para o servidor então :)

Comment: Então cara, no meu servidor não tem nenhum arquivo .json, eu copiei e não mudou nada, não sei oq devo fazer, todavia obrigado.

Comment: @AndréTripodeColognesi mas o .json é só pra gerar o autoload.php, não precisa mandar ele, manda a pasta vendor composer e tá resolvido, ou não?

Comment: @AndréTripodeColognesi você está se equivocando. O `composer.json` por si só não faz nada. Você deve colocar `app` como minusculo no composer.json e, no projeto local, rode `composer dump -o`. Após fazer isso, envie a pasta `vendor` para o servidor novamente (estou supondo que você está usando FTP)

Comment: Estou usando SFTP, enviei a pasta COMPOSER par ao servidor e meu sistema parou, agora estou enviado a VENDOR, obrigado pela ajuda.